# A QUE SE DEBE EL ERROR: DEBUG" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: javascript, nodejs

$ npm run setup

> base-backend@1.0.0 setup C:\Users\PZ\Desktop\base-backend
> DEBUG=app:* node src/infrastructure/setup.js

"DEBUG" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! base-backend@1.0.0 setup: `DEBUG=app:* node src/infrastructure/setup.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the base-backend@1.0.0 setup script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-13T00_39_32_354

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso determinando los comando a traves de package.json, me ha fucnionado instalando cross-env y añadiendolo

```
"start": "cross-env DEBUG=darwin:* && node src/infrastructure/setup.js"
```